# SmartCarve4 Laser Engraving Software

Tags: cad

I'm in use of a CMD-CMA1612T 1250 watt laser engraver connected via Firewire-USB for Controller 1, and via ethernet for Controller 3. All of my projects are being constructed in SmartCarve4.3 on Windows 7.

My issues:

1). Attempted carving on Controller 1 results in the verbatim error message

"Send data overtime,please check USB line and version of mainboard"

The USB connection is fine. Device Manager recognizes the connection on the proper COM port with no alerts or error messages regarding driver installation or device communication. Why am I receiving this error within the program?

2). Attempted exporting of .ycm files via Controller 3 doesn't get me very far. Under File->Net Transfer, I can select a folder containing my .ini file for parameters and my .ycm carving graphics. However, even when I set SmartCarve's IP to match the IP of my engraver, I receive "Error! Failed connection."

I think that my ethernet connection to the engraver is recognized, but my comptuer only tells me that something is connected and that there is no internet access. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cat5e cable was defective. The casing didn't show any damage, but one of the pairs didn't tone.